# Validator of JSON against JSON schema online

Tags: json, validation

I would like to find an online validator of JSON against JSON schema – both provided by URL.

Good example is http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/ but I need to copy&paste the content of JSON file and JSON scheme, not URL of my files.
Do you know any?

Comment: Try this https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ or http://www.freeformatter.com/json-validator.html it will work as per your expectation.

Comment: No, it will not. I do not need validate JSON as such, I need to validate it against JSON schema. See json-schema.org

Answer (score 2):

I know it's an old question, but https://json-schema-validator.herokuapp.com/ seems to do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

To check whether json content is valid or not, try the following json validator -

1. http://jsonlint.com/
2. http://codebeautify.org/jsonvalidator

Comment: I do not need validate JSON as such, I need to validate it against JSON schema. See http://json-schema.org/